# HttpClient with client certificate loaded from file

Tags: c#, iis, dotnet-httpclient, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I want to add mutual authentication to my client .NET application that is running under IIS server (it's a web service that calls another web service). Client app loads client certificate from file and it works fine with the following code on my development machine (I tried Windows 7 and Windows 10 with .NET 4.6.2):

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertPath); -- PFX file with client cert and private key 
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
handler.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;
client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

But when this code is deployed to production Windows 2016 Server machine the application throws `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I enabled tracing for `System.Net` this is what I see in logs

```
SecureChannel#66407304 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.
AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.
Exception in HttpWebRequest#60537518:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

As it turned out this error is caused due to the lack of IIS user's permissions to read private key in PFX file. So when I import it into machine certificate store and add `IIS_IUSRS` by clicking right-button on client certificate `All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys...` everything works fine, but I want to avoid that.

Is there a way to work with client certificate loaded from file on Windows Server and don't import client certificate PFX file into certificate store?

Comment: where is your client running and what kind of application is the client ?  is the client running inside IIS worker process ?  And Where is it throwing the error ? Client side or server side ?

Comment: it's .NET web application that does HTTP call to remote server using client mutual authentication. it is running inside IIS worker process. Error is on client side

Comment: Does it work when you import into the user cert store, or are you using the machine cert store?

Comment: I import it to machine store since it's should be accessed by different user, and yes, it works when I import it and add `IIS_IUSRS` to `All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys...` I will edit question...

Comment: I had the same issue when loading a pfx file under IIS. Turns out I needed to edit the application pool and then enable Load User profile as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate/47506891#47506891

Answer (score 2):

Since the example where things work involve using the machine store, you can try changing to a MachineKeySet load.

Replace

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertPath);
```

with

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertPath, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

This *shouldn't* be necessary for client authentication certificates, but if you have user impersonation happening between load and use that can cause user keyset problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, try X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet. Next as I understand you can just use the key with importing it into key storage. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867243/what-is-the-impact-of-the-persistkeyset-storageflag-when-importing-a-certifica) you should first of all import key into the store (whether persistent or not) and then use the key.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it did not work. I do want to avoid importing keys into the store and work with pfx file as it works on desktop Windows

Comment: What about IIS Application Pool Identity? Did you try to change the default ApplicationPoolIdentity to some user with higher privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add this in the startup code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            (a, b, c, d) => true;
```