# Imported by PS script certificate has broken Private Key

Tags: azure-devops, ssl-certificate, private-key

I'm running CI integration tests in Azure DevOps, running happens on a dedicated Azure VM with installed build agent. Those tests require client SSL certificate to be installed on that VM. As a build step in CI I have a PS script that consumes the Azure KeyVault certificate and imports that into LocalMachine/My store of VM. While the cert is imported and I can see it in VM, tests from CI fail using the cert. Note that the cert, when trying to manually export in VM, has a **Export with Private Key** option grayed out.

When I run the same PS script manually withing VM and then run CI tests (with PS step disabled), tests successfully consumer certificate and pass.

What should I change in my PS script below, so it (being running remotely) would import a certificate with **Export with Private Key** option enabled?

```
$vaultName = "MyKeyVault-stest"
$secretName = "MyCertificate"

$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName
$kvSecretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($kvSecret.SecretValueText)

$kvSecretPass = 'myPass'

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


$pfxCertObject=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @($kvSecretBytes, "", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)

$newcertbytes = $pfxCertObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $kvSecretPass)

$newCert=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$newCert.Import($newcertbytes,$kvSecretPass,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$certStore = Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$openFlags = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite
$certStore.Open($openFlags) 
$certStore.Add($newCert) 

Write-host $env:USERNAME
Write-host $(whoami)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are importing a PFX to add it to a persisted store you want to specify the `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` flag.  If you don't, at some undetermined point later the garbage collector notices no one cares about the key and then asks Windows to delete it... and then the version added to the X509Store can no longer find its key.

Other reading:

- [What is the impact of the `PersistKeySet`-StorageFlag when importing a Certificate in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36867243/6535399)
- [What is the rationale for all the different X509KeyStorageFlags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52750160/6535399)