# Process started using Invoke-Command on remote computer can't load X509 certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, aws-cloudformation, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

Bear with me, as I have a somehow tricky setup in a custom AWS EC2 AMI based on Windows Server 2012.

I orchestrate a machine using CloudFormation. Once the machine is up and provisioned through the UserData part of the provisioning script, I need to launch a daemon on the machine. I do so using PowerShell from a remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command \
    -ComputerName '<IP>' \
    -Credential $cred \
    -ScriptBlock { \
        $res = C:\bootstrap.ps1 C:\daemonlauncher.ps1;
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
        return $res;
    };
```

The contents of `bootstrap.ps1` are:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class "Win32_Process" -Name "Create" -ArgumentList "powershell -File $($args[0])";
```

And the contents of `daemonlauncher.ps1` are simple:

```
# Some PATH environment setup...
Start-Process -FilePath daemon.exe -ArgumentList 8080;
```

This way, I end up having a `daemon.exe` instance running on port 8080. For now, what happened is:

1. `Invoke-Command` executes in the remote machine `bootstrap.ps1`.
2. `bootstrap.ps1` creates a new instance of PowerShell, passing to it `daemonlauncher.ps1`.
3. `daemonlauncher.ps1` starts the `daemon.exe` process and exits. The daemon remains running.

Now, **the tricky part**. `daemon.exe` is used to launch a second process, let's call it `server.exe`. Now, `server.exe` listens on an SSL port using a **self-signed certificate**. However, it fails to load the self-signed certificate, although it is able to create it. `server.exe` is written in C#, and the error it throws is (check the **access denied** part):

```
Error importing certificate 'c:\server\ssl-certificate.pfx': Access denied
```

However, if instead of using `Invoke-Command` from a remote computer to execute `bootstrap.ps1` (step 1) I do so directly from within the target computer, the `server.exe` process can load the certificate with no issues at all.

```
C:\bootstrap.ps1 C:\daemonlauncher.ps1
```

Examining the Security tab of `daemon.exe` with ProcessExplorer, I can see that **the Privileges are different** depending on how I launched it:

- Launching using `Invoke-Command` from the remote machine:

  - All privileges are `Enabled`
- Launching `bootstrap.ps1` manually from the target machine:

  - All privileges are `Disabled` except for:

    - SeChangeNotifyPrivilege > Default Enabled
    - SeCreateGlobalPrivilege > Default Enabled
    - SeDebugPrivilege > Enabled
    - SeImpersonatePrivilege > Default Enabled

I'm at a loss here. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

### Further information

After messing with Process Explorer / Process Monitor I could get this additional info:

When started from the remote machine (using `Invoke-Command`), `daemon.exe` has the correct user (`{MACHINE-NAME}\Administrator`) and correct `SID` under the Security tab.

Checking with Process Monitor, I can see that `server.exe` tries to access `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\{SID}`, but it doesn't try to create any file inside it (I think the CREATE FILE on `ed0352f...` with NAME NOT FOUND result is just the process trying to read it).

```
12:01:42.0687133 PM server.exe  1228    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:01:42.0687908 PM server.exe  1228    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:01:42.0689283 PM server.exe  1228    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500    NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:01:42.0691444 PM server.exe  1228    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500\ed0352ff16ca244170b661836cbecde9_63d47ad1-1696-4af6-bfda-1963bc1d25d0  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
12:01:42.0692365 PM server.exe  1228    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500    SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
12:01:42.0692590 PM server.exe  1228    QueryDirectory  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500\ed0352ff16ca244170b661836cbecde9_* NO SUCH FILE    Filter: ed0352ff16ca244170b661836cbecde9_*
12:01:42.0692752 PM server.exe  1228    CloseFile   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500    SUCCESS
```

When I execute the following line from the remote computer I get that the `Administrator` user profile is loaded (property `Loaded` is `True`). Worth noting everything I'm running is with `-Credential` for `Administrator`:

```
Invoke-Command \
    -ComputerName '<IP>' \
    -Credential $cred` \
    -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_UserProfile";
    };
```

Then, once I run at least once the `daemon.exe` from the target machine (just running step 2 from above directly on the target machine), `server.exe` **DOES CREATE** a file under `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\{SID}` and writes to it (`9a470a...` in this example):

```
12:06:39.3433354 PM server.exe  3420    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:06:39.3434039 PM server.exe  3420    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:06:39.3434697 PM server.exe  3420    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500    NAME COLLISION  Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup, Attributes: S, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
12:06:39.3435435 PM server.exe  3420    CreateFile  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500\9a470a37b16b84cf43ed29a419dfbb0b_63d47ad1-1696-4af6-bfda-1963bc1d25d0  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: S, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Created
12:06:39.3436466 PM server.exe  3420    WriteFile   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500\9a470a37b16b84cf43ed29a419dfbb0b_63d47ad1-1696-4af6-bfda-1963bc1d25d0  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 79, Priority: Normal
12:06:39.3436929 PM server.exe  3420    CloseFile   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-928426534-1735938674-1186316988-500\9a470a37b16b84cf43ed29a419dfbb0b_63d47ad1-1696-4af6-bfda-1963bc1d25d0  SUCCESS
```

Once I have run the program locally once, if I execute all from the beginning from the remote computer `server.exe` can correctly load the certificate **until a machine restart**. Then we are back at the beginning of the issue.

Every time it creates a different file under `...\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21...\`.

Comment: Generally "access denied" when opening a PFX means either: it wants to open user keys, but there isn't a user profile loaded; or it wants to open machine keys and the user doesn't have access to write to the [appropriate directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval#key-directories-and-files).  I don't personally know enough about PS execution to know which seems more likely, but you could force it to one or the other with the MachineKeySet or UserKeySet import flags.

Comment: Thank you for your insights @bartonjs. I have added more information to the question based on what I could find out regarding private key directory permissions and user profile load status!

Comment: For your new variant of the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867243/what-is-the-impact-of-the-persistkeyset-storageflag-when-importing-a-certifica